# Sharepoint documents set to download

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise

I need to post about 20 documents to download on the document library. Most people will want to download all of them at once.  Instead of having them posted individually and then making them download them individually? Or I’m open to any suggestions for how best to post a slew of documents for download? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're doing? Post the docs where? Are you writing code?

Answer (score 0):

You could put all 20 documents in a zip file and then upload that to the document library. Users could then download all files in one go. Alternatively the modern library experience allows users to select multiple files to download.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the files you want, and then drag and drop to join the Document Library:
[image]

To download, select the file you want and click **Download**:
[image]